# gstreamer : how do I pass structure as a argument to g_object_set()?

Tags: c++, c, gobject

Hi all I am currently able to set one property at a time to gstreamer plugin like as fallow.

```
GstElement *source = gst_bin_get_by_name (GST_BIN (m_pu_pipeline), "ue");

g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "objectLeftEnabled", settings.m_b_left, NULL);           
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source), "objectRemovedEnabled", settings.m_b_removed, NULL);
```

But I want to set whole structure at a time like as fallow.

```
g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "lettremoved-settings", settings,  NULL);
```

Following is What I have done so far to set structure directly to gstreamer plugin.

```
struct _LeftRemoved
{
    bool left;
    bool removed;
}; 

//Declaration of copy and free function.
static gpointer lr_copy (gpointer data);
static void lr_free (gpointer data);

G_DEFINE_BOXED_TYPE (_Leftremoved, lettremoved_settings,
                     lr_copy,
                     lr_free);  

//Defination of copy and free.
static gpointer lr_copy (gpointer data)
{
  struct _LeftRemoved *details = (struct _LeftRemoved *)data;
  struct _LeftRemoved *copy = g_new (struct _LeftRemoved, 1);

  // We need to copy 
  copy->left= details->left;
  copy->removed = details->removed;

  g_print("Set Property From Copy left=%d\n",copy->left);
  g_print("Set Property From Copy removed=%d\n",copy->removed);

  return (gpointer) copy;
}


static void lr_free (gpointer data)
{
        //code for free memory.
}

enum ePropertyType
{
   PROP_OBJ_LR
}

static void gst_ivue_class_init (GstIVUEClass * klass)
{  
  GObjectClass *gobject_class;
  GstElementClass *gstelement_class;

  gobject_class = (GObjectClass *) klass;
  gstelement_class = (GstElementClass *) klass;

  gobject_class->set_property = gst_ivue_set_property;
  gobject_class->get_property = gst_ivue_get_property;
  gobject_class->finalize = gst_ivue_finalize;

  GParamSpec *pspec;
  pspec = g_param_spec_boxed ("lettremoved_settings",     "lettremoved_settings", "Left Removed Settings",lettremoved_settings_get_type(), (GParamFlags)G_PARAM_READWRITE);
  g_object_class_install_property (gobject_class, PROP_OBJ_LR, pspec);

}

static void gst_ivue_set_property (GObject * object, guint prop_id, const GValue * value, GParamSpec * pspec)
{
   GstIVUE *filter = GST_IVUE (object);

    switch (prop_id)
    {
       case PROP_OBJ_LR:
            g_boxed_copy(lettremoved_settings_get_type(),&value);
            break;
       default:
            G_OBJECT_WARN_INVALID_PROPERTY_ID (object, prop_id, pspec);
    }
} 

static void gst_ivue_get_property( GObject* object, guint prop_id, GValue* value, GParamSpec* pspec )
{
     GstIVUE* filter = GST_IVUE (object);
     switch (prop_id) 
     {
         case PROP_OBJ_LR:
             // Also I don't know how to get value
     } 
}
```

The above code run successfully but it is not setting value which is provided by me. 
For example If I called g_object_set() function as :

```
   settings.left=true;
   settings.removed=true;
   g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "lettremoved-settings", settings,  NULL);
```

Then in copy function, This code setting the default value as false for both left and removed.
Please help me where I am going wrong.

Comment: please re-label the question as "gobject:" this is not gstreamer specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

g_object_set and g_object_get are varrag functions. That means you can set both in one call:

```
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(source),
  "objectLeftEnabled", settings.m_b_left,
  "objectRemovedEnabled", settings.m_b_removed,
  NULL);
```

Also FYI. in instead of g_new and manually copying you can use g_memdup().

When you tried your boxed type, did you pass a pointer? It could be that you need to call

g_object_set (G_OBJECT (source), "lettremoved-settings", &settings,  NULL);

Comment: thanx for answering , also I have mentioned in my question how to get the value from my function gst_ivue_get_property()  for exapmle if we want to get int value we call g_value_set_int (value, filter->maxH_object); for one value , but now here I want to get _Leftremoved structure so which function should I call ?

Comment: Your gst_ivue_set_property() impl is not right, you are not taking the result of g_boxed_copy there. But please understand that this is not a forum to write code for you. You can look at all the projects on the gnome git and search for projects using g_boxed types (e.g. on the github mirror: https://github.com/gnome/)